# Is Safe JWT Store in Req. Session?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

i have a question about **MERN** Stack (Mysql,Express,React,Node). I confused about storing Jwt token (in Cookies,Localstorage or as session in request).

 What iam asking is **Is Safe Storing JWT On Request Session ?**

 Can someone explain how to store token in Single Page App ?

 Thanks Anyway ...

Comment: i would choose cookie > localstorage. the reason is that you can turn on `httpOnly` on the cookie witch simply means that javascript on the client side cannot read the cookie only the server. you can also set an expire date on the cookie witch you cant on localstorage, you need to manually delete it. if you are using things like Nuxt.js or Next.js that has server side rendering, you will have a scenario where you need to access the token from the server side, and therefore you can read it out of the request headers.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i already use next js too. But i have a problem on backBehaviour (Browser). When that action is triggered, ReactComp has not rendered on the server side (Ex, So when is already logged In, When i press back. Back to login screen (Logic in server side has not triggered).
I Have an idea for that issues, i can store logic in frontend (But I have a problem with storing the sensitive data).
Cookies HttpOnly is Recommended for store the token ?

Comment: @Ifaruki when it comes to SSR the token would be refresh token right? Because we only get the processed html to the client side.

Comment: i personaly use nuxt.js so i dont know exactly the ecosystem of next.js but it should be similar. i do it like this: when i refresh the page, and i am on the server side, i grab the token out of the cookie and store it into the vuex storage (in your case redux i guess) because its httponly and i cannot read it from the client side. saving your token in a store like vuex is ok. a token should not contain sensitive data it can be decoded easely. in my app i just store the mongoDB objectId of the user. thats enough information for my backend to know witch operation the user is allowed to do

Comment: a token has a expire date. that means till that date the token is valid. if somebody steals your token and you log off you usually erase that token from your cookie. but the problem is that the attacker has your token and that token is still valid. people decide to create a blacklist. its just a simple storage on the server. if you log out of your app, you store that token to the blacklist. now if the attacker tries to do something with your token, you need to check first if that token is in that blacklist. if it is you reject the request

Comment: and also, if somebody goes to your computer, opens your devtools and checks the cookies its the fault of the user and not the dev. usually users have a computer password.

Comment: @Ifaruki Are you for each request need token jwt ? you mean store that token in cookies but httpOnly right ? And you need some information stored in redux. (Are store is persisted or only each request is storing ) ?

Comment: @Ifaruki Oh i see, if cookies already httpOnly flag attacked can't be steals the cookie right ?

Comment: httpOnly simply means javascript (the client side) cannot read that cookie. so its not easelie stealable with XSS attacks

Comment: Ouh, ok.
Appreciated your answer, Thankyou verymuch. That information is very usefull for me

Answer (score 1):

When we do a successful login we get an access token. In this case, it is a JWT token. When we get this we need to keep it somewhere to use it for the future use of the user. We normally store that in LocalStorage. You can find more info about LocalStorage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). We also can use SessioStorage, Cookies as well. But Cookies only can contain 4KB of data and SessionStorage will go away when the browser is closed. That is the reason for me to go with LocalStorage. But you can choose it depending on your application requirement.

When sending a request with a token, I use the Authorization header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is safe to store token in localstorage ? When that storage can be access to other people.Best way store in cookies httpOnly (Maybe storing only jwt will be less than 4Kb) ?

Comment: People can take it and read it easily. That's why we need to make sure we aren't storing any sensitive data in it. Only data that we need to bootstrap the user flow. May be user name, user id, user role kind of things. And that token is short lived. About 15 mins. In that way we are less vulnerable to the outside. That's when the refresh token comes into play. That can be stored in cookie with http only and secured flags. That will also contain expiration date. But a larger one around 30 days. We need to clear both when logout.

Comment: Ouh ok, so the only one choices is storing Jwt in cookies But must be turn (httpOnly and Secure flag. Https Access) ya ? Thankyou verymuch for the answer bro

Comment: for refresh token, yes go for cookie. for access token, it is fine to go with localstorage since it is short-lived.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to store JWT cookie at the client and even more in this day and age it necessary for scalability.

What should you use?

- `Session` - This is the "old" way of doing things and no in use anymore. The session saves a state on the API server and that is a bad thing for scaling.
- `Localstorage` - A good choice for **mobile** and **web** applications. The idea here is that you as the client developer are responsible for keeping track of JWT (save it on login, remove it on logout)
- `JWT-Cookie` - is the best for ONLY web application. It's the same idea of Localstorage but now the server is responsible for setting and removing the JWT from the client using the `Set-Cookie` header.

Note: You can implement both `Localstorage` and `JWT-Cookie` side by side.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, `Set-Cookie` in the server that you mean is httpOnly flag ?
So is the best choices is store Jwt in cookies but httpOnly flag MUST be turned on ya ?

Comment: `Set-Cookie` works regardless of `httpOnly`. Having said that `httpOnly` is the more secure because  JS won't be able to access it and it the correct way to set a JWT-Cookie

Comment: Ouh ok, so the best way is Cookies httpOnly. Thankyou anyway

Comment: @Daniel localstorage is the not the secured way, can you tell any other way?

Comment: @RohanDevaki try `JWT-Cookie`. Cookies are more secured

Comment: @daniel,  ok , i will try